# create new page and bind created term with event receiver in SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers, sharepoint-list

I am using [this](http://softlanding.ca/blog/Friendly-URLs-for-SharePoint-List-Items)(http://softlanding.ca/blog/Friendly-URLs-for-SharePoint-List-Items) event receiver to create new friendlyurl for each created Item in custom list.It works fine. As you see in blod it binds all created terms to single page(ListItemDisplay.aspx)

But instead of binding all terms to single page I want to create new page for each list item and bind generated friendlyurl to this page..
Any Idea ?

```
    public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
            UpdateFriendlyUrl(properties);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// An item is being updated.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            base.ItemUpdating(properties);
            UpdateFriendlyUrl(properties);
        }
private bool eventFiringEnabledStatus;
        private string[] listNames = new string[6] { "TempAnnouncement", "Bakanlık Duyuruları", "Basın Duyuruları", "Defterdarlık Duyuruları", "Diğer Duyurular", "Mevzuat Duyuruları" };

        /// <summary>
        /// An item is being updated.
        /// </summary>
        private void UpdateFriendlyUrl(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            try
            {
                //properties.ListTitle
                //if (properties.ListItem == null || properties.Web == null) return;
                if (Array.IndexOf(listNames, properties.ListTitle) == -1) return;

                EventFiringEnabled = false;

                var addedItem = properties.ListItem;
                var webUrl = properties.Web.Url;

                // first, read relevant existing metadata from current item
                var enteredTitle = addedItem["Title"] as string;
                var existingFriendlyUrl = "";
                if (addedItem["ListItemMappedFriendlyURL"] != null &&
                    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(addedItem["ListItemMappedFriendlyURL"].ToString()))
                {
                    var existingFriendlyUrlFldVl = new SPFieldUrlValue(addedItem["ListItemMappedFriendlyURL"].ToString());
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(existingFriendlyUrlFldVl.Url))
                        existingFriendlyUrl = existingFriendlyUrlFldVl.Url;
                }


                var newFriendlyUrl = String.Empty;
                var newFriendlyUrlTermId = String.Empty;
                var createTermResult = false;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
                {
                    using (var site = new SPSite(webUrl))
                    {
                        using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            // TODO: when implementing this solution, replace this URL with the appropriate value for
                            //          the friendly URL of the navigation term that will be the parent of your newly created terms
                            var parentFriendlyTermsUrl = web.Url +"/"+ properties.ListTitle.Replace(" ", String.Empty).ToLower(); // "/Duyurular";

                            //now create a taxonomy term in the navigation term set with the title in the url, and return relevant values
                            createTermResult = CreateTermForBlog(enteredTitle, web, existingFriendlyUrl, parentFriendlyTermsUrl, out newFriendlyUrl, out newFriendlyUrlTermId);
                        }
                    }
                });

                // if we failed to generate a valid friendly URL, don't proceed.
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(newFriendlyUrl) || !createTermResult) return;

                // set the friendly url & navigation taxonomy term id field
                var newFriendlyUrlFieldVal = new SPFieldUrlValue { Description = newFriendlyUrl, Url = newFriendlyUrl };
                addedItem["ListItemMappedFriendlyURL"] = newFriendlyUrlFieldVal;

                // set the friendly url taxonomy term ID if we have it.
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(newFriendlyUrlTermId))
                    addedItem["ListItemNavigationTermId"] = "#0" + newFriendlyUrlTermId;
                // the #0 is added because the {Term.id} property in the web part query parameters list has that at the beginning for some reason
                //   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx

                addedItem.Update();
            }
            catch (Exception outerEx)
            {
                // TODO: log exception.
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                EventFiringEnabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you check the link again, it shows blog not found error ? also if possible can you share the code and what you have tried?

Comment: I have checked link it looks fine but also shared the exact remote url and the code..